# Kura org.eclipse.osgi plug-in is missing from this configuration

Tags: kura

As shown in the images below, whenever I run Eclipse, it prompts that the **org.eclipse.osgi** plug-in is missing from this configuration. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. From the Eclipse Workbench main menu, from Help dropdown > click Install New Software.
2. Click Available Software Site
3. Scroll down Preference left payne and expand plug-in Development.
4. Click Target Platform > Add to open New Target Platform
5. Check radio button Template (Base RCP) > Next
6. Select Locations Tab > click Add to open Add Content
7. Select Installation > Next
8. From dropdown Locations > select ${eclipse_home} > Next
9. Select Content > click deselect All
10. Select org.eclipse.osgi  from the list
11. Click Finish > Ok

Answer (score 0):

Did you import and setup the target-definition correctly as described on [Setting up the Kura Development Environment](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/dev/kura-setup.html)?

Also keep in mind that the Kura Emulator is currently not supported for Windows environments.